# Keep only last six months data in Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

`from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta`

I did

`df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`
`six_months = date.today() - relativedelta( months = +6)`
`df = df.loc[(df['Date'] >= six_months)]`

I kept getting following error
`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'`

Can someone help me to grap just last six months data from df?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
df['Date'].last('6M')
```

Comment: I did this and worked ```df2= df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False).set_index("Date").last("6M")```